# Evaluate double integral $\iint_A \min(x,y)\,dx\,dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I have function
$$f(x,y) = min(x,y) $$
And Area
$$A = [0,a]\times[0,a]$$
How can i found this? (with lebesgue measure)
$$\iint_A f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$
Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express the integral in two parts,

$$\int_A  \min(x,y)\>dxdy$$
$$=\int_0^adx\int_0^x ydy + \int_0^ady\int_0^y xdx=\frac{a^3}{3}$$

Comment: can you give us a little more detailed explanation?

Comment: @12345654321 - Sure. Think of two regions: min(x,y) = y in the region enclosed by x=a, y = 0 and y=x. On the other hand, min(x,y) = x in the region enclosed by x=0, y = a and y=x. And, integrate them separately.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is as follows. Note that $$\min(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}[x+y-|x-y|].$$
Thus, we have:
$$\int\int_{A}\min(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}(x+y)dxdy -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)dydx -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{y}(y-x)dxdy$$
Now, these integrals are easy to compute:
$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{a}(x+y)dxdy = a^{3}$$ 
$$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)dydx = \int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{y}(y-x)dxdy =\frac{a^{3}}{6}$$
so our final result is:
$$\int\int_{A}\min(x,y)dxdy = \frac{1}{2}[a^{3}-2\frac{a^{3}}{6}] = \frac{a^{3}}{3}$$